# ECC key encoding in pyecc and seccure

Tags: python, encryption, public-key-encryption, elliptic-curve

I am working with [pyecc](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/PyECC) which uses the [seccure C library](http://point-at-infinity.org/seccure/).

When a public key is generated I get something back like this:

```
#Gp}7RRWK5Dyg&-m5yHve1p{?<o0xi.M8-?W^]xb))oA]|qO%[5v?#IxteV?
```

Are these the 'raw bytes' or is this encoded in some form? When I use `os.urandom(16)` I get all kinds of messed up characters, but not from this generate public key function. Does that mean that there is some encoding? I've looked at the [seccure source code](https://github.com/slideinc/PyECC/blob/master/seccure/libseccure.c), but I still don't understand why I get all these 'normal' characters.

How do I turn this into a byte array (Python bytearray) of the exact key?

Code:

```
from pyecc import ECC
ecc = ECC.generate()
print ecc._public
```

Comment: Please show the code you are using to generate the key.

Answer (score 2):

It looks like it might be a proprietary format from quickly looking at their code.  They serialize and compress the key information into a printable string.  You can download the source code and see an example of how to use it here: http://point-at-infinity.org/seccure/.